# Laravel Update creating new ID

Tags: laravel

I am following a tutorial and everything is working.  The only problem is when I update category ID 1 and submit, I have now Category ID 2 with the updated data and Category ID 1 is still the same.  Not sure what to do.  I really need to continue but not sure how to fix this.

```php
public function addEditCategory(Request $request, $id = NULL)
{
    if(empty($id)) {
        $title = "Add Category";
        $category = new Category;
        $categorydata = array();
        $getCategories = array();
        $message = "Category added successfully!";
    } else {
        $title = "Edit Category";
        $categorydata = Category::where('id', $id)->first();
        $getCategories = Category::with('subcategories')
            ->where([
                'parent_id' => 0,
                'section_id' => $categorydata['section_id']
            ])
            ->get();
           
        $category = Category::find($id);
        $message = "Category updated successfully!";
    }
    
    if($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $data = $request->all();
        $rules = [
            'category_name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
            'section_id' => 'required',
            'url' => 'required',
            'category_image' => 'image',
        ];

        $customMessages = [
            'category_name.required' =>'Category Name is required',
            'category_name.regex' => 'Valid Category Name is required',
            'section_id.required' => 'Section is required',
            'url.required' => 'Category URL is required',
            'category_image.image' => 'Valid Category Image is required',
        ];
       
        // $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
             
        if($request->hasFile('category_image')) {
            $image_tmp = $request->file('category_image');
            if($image_tmp->isValid()) {
                $extension = $image_tmp->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $imageName = rand(111,99999).'.'.$extension;
                $imagePath = public_path('/uploads/admin/images/category_images/' . $imageName);
                Image::make($image_tmp)->save($imagePath);
                $category->category_image = $imageName;
            }
        }

        if(empty($data['category_discount'])) {
            $data['category_discount'] = blank('');
        }

        if(empty($data['description'])) {
            $data['description'] = "";
        }

        if(empty($data['meta_title'])) {
            $data['meta_title'] = "";
        }

        if(empty($data['meta_description'])) {
            $data['meta_description'] = "";
        }

        if(empty($data['meta_keywords'])) {
            $data['meta_keywords'] = "";
        }
        
        if(empty($data['url'])) {
            $data['url'] = "";
        }

        $category->parent_id = $data['parent_id'];
        $category->section_id = $data['section_id'];
        $category->category_name = $data['category_name'];
        $category->category_discount = $data['category_discount'];
        $category->description = $data['description'];
        $category->url = $data['url'];
        $category->meta_title = $data['meta_title'];
        $category->meta_description = $data['meta_description'];
        $category->meta_keywords = $data['meta_keywords'];
        $category->status = 1;
        $category->save();
            
        Session::flash('success', $message);
        return redirect('admin/categories');
    }

    $sections = Section::get();
    return view('admin.categories.add_edit_category')->with(compact('title', 'sections', 'categorydata', 'getCategories'));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the id is properly set? try adding `dd($id, empty($id));` as the first line of this long function and check the results when you try to update ID 1.

Comment: It comes back as 1 for the id and false for empty($id)....How do I fix this

Comment: instead of `if ( empty($id) )` check if it's null. `if ( $id === null )`. `empty()` is a function used to check the emptiness of an array. You're misusing it here.

Comment: I changed to this and I still get a new ID when I edit:                                   
       if($id===null){            
            $title = "Add Category";
            $category = new Category;
            $categorydata = array();
            $getCategories = array();
            $message = "Category added successfully!";
        } else {

Comment: First of all, why all this in one action, you could set the action of add/update method in your frontend, but this no one will understand it even you when gonna back to it someday!
it is hard to maintain, please do a favor and organize your class ( just an advice u can ignore this comment)

Comment: I don't know.  I am learning and came upon a tutorial.  Just trying to figure out why I get a duplicate ID.  I will def organize it once I figure out why

Answer (score 1):

That code is a disaster, you have the index, create, update method in the same controller, what course are you seeing? I recommend you see another.

Answer (score 0):

1.You have to Debug and check are you sending id everytime empty or not. might be update category also empty id is passing then you have to send id while updating.
2.Once you pass id while updating dd($id) and check its format and data type resolve it and update if condition it will fix your problem.